# How to prefix .net core app with url from a application under a website?

Tags: .net, iis, visual-studio-2017, iis-express

I have a .net core simple app, which I need to install on a server as an Application under a website.

[image]


This is the link for app on IIS (on deploy server)

[image]


This is how I want to start the app. **I don't want to change URLfrom App URL, I want to append remote server automatically that url to my paths (local paths)**

What should I do? (c# code, web.config) I want to work on the server, because locally works very fine. On server I have Errors because it tries to find localhost/dist/somefiles not localhost/myapp/dist/somefiles or it tries to call localhost/api/something not localhost/myapp/api/something.

[image]

Comment: You can use Jexus Manager to configure, but whether VS likes that is unknown. https://jexusmanager.com

Comment: Yes, I know, but I want to make that change from code...

Comment: From where? Web server configuration is decoupled from code intentionally.

Comment: I want to modify my project code to do that, web.config or something...

Comment: Is it possible?

Comment: Could I write a rule in Web.config which do that redirect? I tried something but throws 301 error code (too many redirects)

Answer (score 0):

You have to use
"launchUrl": "myApp" under launchsettings.json

Under -> solution->properties->launchSettings.json you need to add the above parameter.

```
Example:
{
  "iisSettings": {
    "windowsAuthentication": false,
    "anonymousAuthentication": true,
    "iisExpress": {
      "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:19947/OASISCore",
      "sslPort": 44329
    }
  },
  "profiles": {
    "OASISCore": {
      "commandName": "Project",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      },
      "applicationUrl": "https://localhost:7088;http://localhost:5088",
      "launchUrl": "myApp",
      "dotnetRunMessages": true
    },
    "IIS Express": {
      "commandName": "IISExpress",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      }
    }
  }
}
```